# HTML5 Webcam Allow Event Handler

Tags: html, events, event-handling, webcam

Is there any way I can catch the event of the user clicking on "allow" camera using the HTML5 webcam in chrome? If so, can you give me an example.

To be more specific, I want to know if the user clicked to allow or deny using the webcam.
For instance, when the user clicks on "allow" I want to display a big message on the screen saying that he is allowing the webcam.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't listen to those click events.  You can't even assume such a dialog was shown, or that a click event would be what selected an option if it was - it could just as easily be some sort of swipe based UI or a phone or tablet.  The actual mechanism for requesting permission is an implementation detail which the spec purposely leaves up to the implementers.

But you can assume that if your success callback for `getUserMedia()` is called then the user has selected allow.  If you get [a `PERMISSION_DENIED` in the error callback](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/getusermedia.html#navigatorusermediaerror-and-navigatorusermediaerrorcallback) then you can be sure the user selected deny.